# Form Inputs in Modal Window not responsive to click using UI-Bootstrap / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have one heck of a problem and I can't think of a solution. I have a Web App that uses AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap (angular-ui-bootstrap). Within my app I have written a service that will open a modal window with a specific view when an event happens, such as a click event. Now in the views that are opened within the window are forms so users can update their personal details, etc, etc... Now I have noticed that when clicking on HTML form inputs in the views contained in the Modal Window (for example, Select, input) the interface is not responsive. So the select options are not shown or the keyboard to type is not available. In Chrome on Android there is no functionality, it's as if the click just isn't resisted. In Firefox it is very slow but options are shown. In iOS performance is slow and unreliable. When I create a clone of the inputs in views that are not part of a modal view there is no issue.

Here is part of my modal service to give you an idea... I have extended the `$modal` from UI-Bootstrap

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .factory('ModalService', ['$modal', function ($modal) {
        // I have only included one method but we have many...

      var modal = angular.copy($modal);
      modal.addProfileChildren = function (childData) {

            var options = {
                templateUrl: '/an/views/modals/modal-profile-add-children.html',
                controller: 'ProfileAddChildrenCtrl',
                windowClass: 'add-children-modal',
                resolve: {
                    modalData: function () {

                        return {
                            childData: childData
                        };
                    }
                }
            };

            return modal.open(options);
        };

        return modal;
    }]);
```

Here is the view that is called by the templateUrl (this is /an/views/modals/modal-profile-add-children.html)

```
    <form name="childrenForm" data-ng-submit="setChildren(children)" novalidate>

    <!-- List Existing Children Here -->
    <div class="container-fluid u-no-padding-hori">
        <div data-ng-repeat="existingKid in existingChildren" data-delete-child="{{existingKid.id}}" class="row question-wrapper u-no-margin-horiz">
            <div class="col-xs-2 affiliation-icon"><span class="icon-ic_kids"></span></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="affiliation-main" data-ng-bind="existingKid.title"></div>
                <div class="affiliation-sub" data-ng-bind="existingKid.text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right"><span class="u-icon-circle icon-ic_trash u-text-color-blue"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- clicking on the select below should provide a dynamic form when I click in a mobile browser NOTHING happens -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 u-padding-top-s question-footer">
                <select ng-model="children.number"
                        data-ng-options="kid.label for kid in childrenDefault track by kid.value">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" data-ng-repeat="child in getNumber(children.number.value) track by $index">
        <!-- loads of dynamic stuff here -->
    </div>
```

It's really strange as in desktop browsers I have no issue, when I put similar forms in views that are not included in the modal windows the functionality works as we would expect. Has anyone experienced this before? Please note that in my index HTML I do have the following meta tag which was suggested as a solution in a similar question

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;" />
```

Please note that in the browser console there are no errors shown, I don't even have any warnings.

Comment: Can you add a plnkr please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic over! I found a solution after reading the following: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2280 - It seems there is a conflict with ngTouch and the modal service with UI-Bootstrap. This was fixed!

Then I simply updated the Ui-Bootstrap library in Bower from "`angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0"`, to `"angular-bootstrap": "0.14.3"`

I'm so happy and relieved I could kiss someone!